# Delete documents from collection based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to delete the documents from a collection(Collection1) which are not matching with other collection(Collection2).

collection1 document - `{_id: <autogen>, items: [{key:'key', ...}}]`

collection2 document - `{_id: 'key', action: {key1:'key1', ...}}, {_id: 'non_matching_key', action: {key1:'key1', ...}}`

Delete all the documents from collection2, where items.key in collection1 is not matching with _id in collection2. with reference to the above example, a document with key-value 'non_matching_key' should be delete from collection2. There would be similar documents in collection2 like the one with _id value 'non_matching_key'.

The approach I thought was for mark and sweep.

- I will add the column in collection2 documents for matching ids(in collection2 with items.key in collection1). This is mark step
- Delete all the documents from collection2 where newly added column do not exists. This is sweep step.

Could you please advise if there is a better way of doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully clear how your documents look like and what are the exact conditions, but you could do it like this:

```
var ids = db.collection1.find({}, { "item.key": 1 }).toArray();
db.collection2.deleteMany({ _id: { $nin: ids } });
```

Comment: Thanks, $nin is the 'key', got that. I will try this. There is an update in the document structure. The structure got changed and now 'items' is an array in collection1. Updated the original post.

Comment: Update: re new strucutre.      Structure : document – {a: b:[c:’’]}
 
 
var finalArray = [];
 
var ids = db.smaDoc.find({"a.b.c": { $exists: true}}, {'a.b.c': 1, _id: 0})
.limit(10).forEach(function(document) {
for(var i=0;i<document.a.b.length;i++) {
print(document.a.b[i].c);
finalArray.push(document.a.b[i].c);
}});       got the flattened array element which can be used to delete query with nin operator. thnx

Comment: Also, can the above query to get the finalArray improved?

Comment: I could help if you provide proper sample data. The fake structure you provided is not really useful.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you want to iterate over your collection 2 and get all the ids that are not in collection 1 and delete those or vice versa.

```
db.collection2.find({}).forEach((doc) => db.collection1.deleteOne({_id: {$ne: doc._id}}))

or

let idsToDelete = db.collection2.find({}).distinct('_id')
let deleteResponse = db.collection1.deleteMany({_id: {$nin: idsToDelete}})
```

SWAP the collection name in the case of the other way.

NOTE: The code is just to give an overview and is not tested.

Comment: The first one will be very slow, I would no recommend at all.